# UnsupportedEncodingException issue

Tags: java, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to create a link with `URLEncoder` but I obtain the `UnsupportedEncodingException` and I don't know why?

```
String param1="a";
String param2="b";
String key="key";
String h="h";

public static void main(String[]args){
    try {
         URLEncoder.encode(param1,key);
         URLEncoder.encode(param2, h);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of URLEncoder?

Comment: This is clearly a case of RTFM. What do you think your calls to `URLEncoder.encode` are doing exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLEncoder.encode takes two parameters.

1st: Value to be encoded.

2nd: Name of the encoding (e.g UTF-8)

So in your case, you would want to do something like this:

```
    static String param1 = "a";
    static String param2 = "b";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
            url.append("&key=");
            url.append(URLEncoder.encode(param1, "UTF-8"));
            url.append("&h=");
            url.append(URLEncoder.encode(param2, "UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless this is inside of a loop the StringBuilder isn't necessary as the compiler will write that code for you.